# Make a bootloader using the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, ide, bootloader

I'm fooling around with OS dev but don't know where to start with making a bootloader in the Eclipse IDE(preferably using C and some asm) so where would I start?

Comment: I said where would I start to make a bootloader using the IDE. Read closer.

Comment: No, you read closer. You said you `don't know where to start with making a bootloader in the Eclipse IDE(preferably using C and some asm)`. Questions have question marks (?). What you wrote is a statement of fact

Comment: I think the real question should be if you can create a bootloader using notepad or edit.com

Comment: I know you can and use FASM, but I can't get it to work with the eclipse ide.

Comment: Why would FASM work with Eclipse?

Comment: And do you suffer from blindness? "I think the real question should be if you can create a bootloader using notepad or edit.com", I replied from that

Comment: No, you didn't. You need to learn how replying works, you replied to my question about using FASM with Eclipse. I really think you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Jesus dude how do you not see that I replied to hexa?

Comment: How would I know that when you don't even know how to reply correctly using the @ symbol?

Comment: I have to automaticly use @ when its obvious that im replying to someone. Right. Totally logical.

Comment: This question is almost an hour old now, and still nobody has asked about the elephant in the room: ___Why on earth does it seem important to you to use Eclipse for that?___ That's hilarious. Of what importance is the choice of editor to the task at hand?

Comment: Do you see a reply button? No. It's not obvious you are replying to anyone but the last commenter when you don't even mention hexa in your comment!

Comment: @Someguynamedpie You know, when you come an ask a question, the basic idea is to be polite. Your question is... poor, to say the least, and when people tell you, you react by getting angry. Don't be surprised if you eat flame with such an attitude.

Comment: Here is a perfect example 0A, since you have posted in front of sbi.
@sbi: Theres nothing wrong with using Eclipse, I simply just have a problem getting it to compile in it.

Comment: you need to read this, then come back and ask a proper question: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: @Someguynamedpie So the problem is not the bootloader development, the problem is Eclipse. You could rewrite your question around that. Or maybe just drop this one and write a new question.

Comment: @Someguynamedpie: You might be annoyed about those picking nits about your question and your comments, but bear in mind that this is a programmer's forum, and ___picking nits is what we do for a living___. You have now learned that people prefer to have a ___clear question___ with a prominent question mark at the end, and that they prefer the @ syntax for ___comment replies___. Yes, IMO, too, they could have been a bit friendlier, but since you ask them to ___help you for free___, I suggest you ___thank them___ for explaining this and move on trying to ___heed that advice___.

Comment: If you word it that way then yeah, I guess it is me having a problem with the IDE. I'll recreate the question either later today or tomorrow. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

The question seem to suggest that you don't know C, ASM or eclipse and probably don't know much about bootloaders.
So the obvious answer would be to start learning the parts

- learn how to program in C
- learn how to program in ASM
- learn about how to program bootloaders
- learn how to use eclipse (CDT)

Comment: How did you gather that from the question? I know C, Some asm(I was hoping to learn some more about it here), I know about bootloaders(just not how to make one) and I use eclipse daily.

Comment: The phrase "where to start" seems to suggest that you have no clear idea about what you are trying to do. It is so general that no one could give a precise answer. If you specify what you know and what you don't know maybe someone could point in the correct direction. Such a general question is just to broad ... one can answer with a link to a C programming tutorial, with an explanation about how to develop with CDT, with an introduction to bootloaders ...

Comment: I just want to know where I could start to make a bootloader using the Eclipse IDE, I don't know how I would make it any more specific to be honest.

Comment: What do you expect as answer?

Comment: An example of what to do, to the extent to get me started.

Comment: @Someguy: exactly what do you want to know about? What kind of code you need to write? What kind of configuration you need to use in Eclipse to have a nice development environment for this? Something else? You need to be specific.

Comment: Hmm, would saying something like "I would like to use gcc/++ or cygwin to make a bootloader in the eclipse IDE to print some text, how would I do that" be more reasonable?

Comment: @Someguy: well, would the answer "you write the bootloader code to print text and run `g++` on it, or press Build in Eclipse" suit you? You're having trouble writing the code, or compiling it?

Comment: I tried compiling an example and no part of it compiled correctly.

Comment: An example of a question that potentially could be answered would be: "I have the following example code [past source code]. I created an eclipse project with CDT and configured the compilers in the preferences the following way: [steps explained]. But the code did not compile. I get the following error messages [error messages]. Why does eclipse does not compiling the code?"

Comment: Thats the thing, the assembly error messages is the whole program. I didn't configure the IDE at all since I didn't know what to do. But I agree I was being kind of bland with the question. I'll be more specific next time. Thank you for your time.